# Need map visualization tool which treats countries like bars in a bar chart

Tags: javascript, google-maps, data-visualization, cartography

I've been searching the internet for a package which can create a simply global map.
There are several which I've searched, webgl globe, kartograph, cartodb, R etc.

None of these have what I'm looking for.

What I'm looking for:
I want a map of the globe, which has two colours for the each country.
there would be a background colour, then the second colour would fill from the bottom by x percent based on an input. For example, if I created a map of gun owners as a percentage over the US map, the background colour would be cream and the second colour would fill the map 55% which represents the amount of gun owners.

So, basically, the second colour in the map would act like a bar chart which fills the colour of the country by the % being applied to the country/area.

Please let me know if any .js library or which tools might be able to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take any [SVG map](http://www.svg-maps.com/) of the world and change every country into a [mask](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/masking.html#Masking) with two `rects` below it. Do the rest with a simple loop and `svgTopOfTwoElements.style.setProperty("height", heightPercentage, "")`. Just search google for getting started with SVG from javascript (it's practically the same as working with HTML elements). The only possible concern would be that [17% of the users don't support SVG (IE8-)](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg), but for the ease of use you get in return I would believe this to be an acceptable price.

Comment: That would fill the country completely instead of just a portion

Comment: My bad, apologies. You could simply convert the svg countries to masks with a few global replaces and below it have two `rects`. Edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Oktav: it would fill just a portion(proportional to the 55% metric)

Comment: David Mulder: Thank you for your input, I will look into this